# My SQL project completed the build successfully but could not find the dacpac file in drop folder

Tags: tfs

I created a SQL Server project. It completed the build successfully but could not find the dacpac file in drop folder.

I did the same thing in our test environment.  I am able to build and deploy successfully.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Which build are you using the old XAML build or new vNext build？ Could you also share the related build definition? And what's result if you manually run the build on the build agent?

Comment: Also, can you provide a build logs (at least logs related to build)?